# python : variables in a list and outside a list

Tags: python, list, global

I have a number of global variables set to False, and then I have all of these variables in a list:

```
var1 = False
var2 = False

var_list = [var1, var2]

$ print var_list
  False, False
```

later in the script the global variables are set to True in a function:

```
def var1_to_true():
    global var1
    var1 = True
```

However, the variables in the list remain False:

```
$ print var1
  True
$ print var_list
  False, False
```

How do I change them too?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot do what you want. Rebinding a variable doesn't set other references to the same objects.

Comment: You want to [read this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @Martijn Thanks, the article is comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible work around for this problem is something simple like this:

```
def get_my_list():
    return [var1, var2]

var1 = False
var2 = False

print get_my_list()
>>> [False, False]

var1 = True

print get_my_list()
>>> [True, False]
```

Then you just use `get_my_list()` in place of where you had the list before.  Having trouble imaging why you may need to do this, but it should meet the requirement.

Comment: I wanted to use this to iterate through the list and write the variable values to a file. I'm new to this and that's the way I thought it would work.

Comment: You could also use `for each in [var1, var2]:`. That will give you the most recent setting in each.